# Setting the position of GridBagLayout at the top of JPanel in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, gridbaglayout

I have written the following code to add a `JLabel` to a `JPanel` but it displays it in the center, while I expected it to be placed at the top of the `JPanel`.

Here is the piece of code I'm referring to:

```
JPanel pnlProjects = new JPanel();
pnlProjects.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 300));
GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
pnlProjects.setLayout(gridBagLayout);
GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

// add multiple label dynamically;
for (int count = 0; count < project.length; count++) {
    lblProjects[count] = new JLabel("Project"+count );
    lblProjects[count].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    lblProjects[count].setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    lblProjects[count].setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(0));
    lblProjects[count].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
    gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = count;
    pnlProjects.add(lblProjects[count], gridBagConstraints);
}

// Add project panel in to the scorllPan
JScrollPane jspProjectlist = new JScrollPane(pnlProjects);
```

[image]

Would anyone be ablt to explain to me how to change it as per my requirement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use next trick: add next code after your loop:

```
gridBagConstraints.weighty=1;
gridBagConstraints.gridy++;
pnlProjects.add(new JLabel(" "), gridBagConstraints);
```

That dummy `JLabel` will grab all space under your project `JLabel`'s.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the such a perfect answer and is this surly proper way?

Comment: That's specific of `GridBagLayout`, I always use dummy components for grabbing empty space.